# SQL error 1064 DECLARE @VAR

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working out the examples in the book *"Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel"*. One of the source files (called `LoadSQLServer.sql`) begins with:

```
CREATE DATABASE SQLBook;

USE SQLBook;

DECLARE @LOADDIR VARCHAR(255) = '/somedir/testdata';
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

/*

more queries

*/
```

I tried to run the script with: `mysql -u root < LoadSQLServer.sql`

However I get the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE LOADDIR VARCHAR(255) = '/somedir/testdata'' at line 1

---

Prior to getting stuck with the above script, I managed to successfully run the following script (called `script.sql`):

```
CREATE DATABASE customer;   

USE customer;                                                            

CREATE TABLE customerslist (                                                
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                         
    forename VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,                                          
    surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,                                           
    PRIMARY KEY (id) );

/*

more queries

*/
```

with the command `mysql -u root < script.sql`. In this script there is no `DECLARE` statement so the problem in `LoadSQLServer.sql` should be in such statement. How to solve this problem?

I'm working on Ubuntu and the output of `mysql --version` is:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the load file for SQL Server. MySQL was not an appropriate database for the book (that changed with version 8.0), so there is no load file for it.

If you are on a suitable computer, you can download SQL Server Express.  Otherwise, I would recommend that you download Postgres and use that version.

Note: As the author of the book, this is the correct course of action.

Comment: Now is clearer to me, MySQL, PostgresSQL and [MS] SQL Server are three distinct implementations of the SQL language. And `LoadSQLServer.sql` gave error because my system has MySQL but the script is for SQL Server. Fortunately, there is another script provided in the book called, `LoadPostgres.sql`. I will install PostgresSQL and try out the script.

Comment: Update: I was able to run the script `LoadPostgres.sql` with Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
(sequel CHAR)
CONCAT(@sequel)
```

@variables are totally independent of non-@ variables.

Two fixes needed:

- `SET @SQL = CONCAT(@sequel);` --> `SET @SQL = sequel;`
- `(sequel CHAR)` --> `(sequel VARCHAR(999))`

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96161/how-to-solve-error-1064-42000